Nissan pulsar n15 low fuel pressure
The fuel pressure it’s low when the car takes the correct temperature. I change the fuel pump and pressure regulator

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not really understanding what you're saying. Is the fuel pressure right when everything is cold? What does "takes the correct temperature" mean? You changed both the fuel pump and regulator, and you're still having the same issue, correct? Where are you measuring the fuel pressure at?
